# NET Core 3.1: update a field of an entity when is inserting and updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I am creating a REST API in NET Core 3.1. I have a table called `GrRefBancos` with columns to audit who and when insert or updated registers. How can I fill these columns automatically without having to send the values when an insert or update happens?

This is my code:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreadoEl { get; set; }
    public string CreadoPor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActualizaEl { get; set; }
    public string ActualizaPor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InactivaEl { get; set; }
}

public partial class GrRefBancos : BaseEntity
{
    public GrRefBancos()
    {
        IcFacturas = new HashSet<IcFacturas>();
        PrFacturas = new HashSet<PrFacturas>();
    }

    public string CodigoBanco { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IcFacturas> IcFacturas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PrFacturas> PrFacturas { get; set; }
}
```

In the `DbContext`, I tried with `HasDefaultValue()` function to insert, but it didn't work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GrRefBancos>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                    .HasName("PK_grrefbancos")
                    .IsClustered(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.ActualizaEl).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.ActualizaPor)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.CodigoBanco)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreadoEl)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);

                entity.Property(e => e.CreadoPor)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasDefaultValue("LoogedUser")
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Descripcion)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.InactivaEl)
                    .HasColumnName("InactivaEL")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");
            });
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override `SaveChanges()` or `SaveChangesAsync()`. Then, you'll need to grab `ChangeTracker` and ask it for all entity entries by `changeTracker.Entries()`.

Iterate over the collection returned, check `Entry.State` to see whether it is an insertion or an update and modify the auditing columns accordingly.

Your `DbContext` will need to be aware of the user who is performing the operation, however that is easy to take care of through clever use of DI. If DI is not possible due to circular dependencies, then raise an event from the `SaveChanges[Async]()` override above and ask for user name.

P.S.: You can decide to not make them part of your model by making the auditing columns shadow EF properties.

Comment: This solution works for me, I used ChangeTracker  in dbcontext and override SaveChanges function to update the timestamps fields. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

With a trigger on the tables. And defining them as Computed in the EfCore meta model so Ef does not try to update them.

This will not work, though, because under a sane modern setup with connection pooling the database has no idea who the user actually is. The date / timestamp is "simple" - the user name is simply not available on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, by trigger doesn't work because the database don't know the real user from the app. I need to make it by code. I'm new in Net Core and I have been looknig for a solution, but in the doc I read says, to insert define a default value witn HasDefaultValue, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Nope. YOu need to program it into the methods where you do the update. Or into SaveChanges going through all changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this feature in your BaseRepository Class

```
class BaseRepository<T>{
     private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
     public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext){
           _dbContext = dbContext;
     }
     public Update(T Entity, UserEntity userEntity){
            //Do anything you like here
     }
     public Insert(T Entity, UserEntity userEntity){
            //Do anything you like here
     }
}
```

and use it like this

```
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<MyRepository>().Update(MyEntity,UserEntity);
//or
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<MyRepository>().Insert(MyEntity,UserEntity);
```

You can Implement your Services to do it automatically maybe pass the HttpContext.User!

```
_myEntityService.Update(myDto,HttpContext.User);
//or
_myEntityService.Insert(myDto,HttpContext.User);
```

It is defiantly possible and the technical implementation totally depends on what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Wring place (there is an override) AND - assuming someone is using the Repository pattern, which is a prooven antipattern and that I yet have to see PROPERLY implemented after 20 years.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion @TomTom You are absolutely correct however I believe Generic Repositories are totally fine for crud purpose. The example is pretty Simplified but can you tell me more about the implementation problem you are talking about. I'm a beginner and I can use your help to polish the code here.

Comment: WHat it is is useless dead code for simple things (i.e. you gain nothing - you HAVE a repository and unit of work, they are called DbContext. Once you get into more compelx sceanrios Repository totally are bad in 99.999% of the implementations. Like your update - i should update only ONE thing, but what about referenced items? What about loading - a repositry can not properly handle Include without using other repositories, which repository-implementers ALWAYS seem to forget. At the end it is a TON of code you can do without wihh exactly the same functionality. Adding useless code = bad.